# How to change brightness of iphone from application

Tags: iphone, screen, light

Hi All I wont to ask one more question !!!

I search through internet and cant find answer on my question maybe somebody here can help me to find answer for my question. In my iPhone application i want settings bar and I want to insert in my settings "**Brightness**" when user change "**Brightness**" setting the iPhone screen brightness must be changed !!! Who can tell me how can I do this !!!

[image]

Comment: You can't, only a private API does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using the current SDK.

Comment: I'm sorry the correct answer isn't what you want it to be, but this simply isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen one or two apps that simulate changing the brightness by overlaying a view and modifying the opacity to make it darker.

Obviously there's no real way to make it brighter.